# Enumerate over a collection to return an array of a property

Tags: vb.net, zedgraph

In ZedGraph there's the PointPairList that conveniently stores all your x's and y's. I'm trying to get just the x-values and y-values without having to do it this:

```
dim xValues = new double(pointList.count) {}
dim yValues = new double(pointList.count) {}

for i = 0 to pointList.count - 1
    xValues(i) = pointList(i).x
    yValues(i) = pointList(i).y
next
```

I rather use something like

```
dim xValues = (double()) pointList.AsEnumerable(point => point.x)
dim yValues = (double()) pointList.AsEnumerable(point => point.y)
```

That code is completely made up, but I hope you see what I'm trying to get across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what a PointPairList is I think that  you could write your selection as such

```
Dim xValues = pointList.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(point) point.X)
```

I am not sure if the AsEnumerable is really required. But you could easily try removing it and check what the compiler has to say.

Comment: You're right. You don't need the `AsEnumerable()`, but for completeness adding `.ToArray()` on the end fits the bill to what I was looking for. Thanks!